# Has someone used QSockeNotifier (Qt library) to read/write serial ports in Linux?

Tags: qt, serial-port

I am currently linux API like `sigio`,`sigaction`, etc. to interface with serial ports in Linux. And for a GUI I am using Qt 4.2. I know about 3rd party QextSerial but I would stay away from it. I also was tinkering with QSocketNotifier as an alternative.

Can someone give a rough example to read/write from a serial port using QSockeNotifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the [docs](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.2/qsocketnotifier.html) for the class. And [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#v62Esu4nQhs/kdenetwork-689144/kppp/modem.cpp&q=kdenetwork%20modem.cpp) is an example for using QSocketNotifier with serial ports.

Also there was another question which might help you, it is written in Python, but pretty clear:

**[How do I watch a serial port with QSocketNotifier (linux)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789304/how-do-i-watch-a-serial-port-with-qsocketnotifier-linux)**